# DependencyProperty типа IList - изменение коллекции

Tags: c#, .net, wpf, xaml

Есть некий `UserControl`. У него есть свойство зависимостей `ItemsProperty` типа `IList<string>` (да да, именно строго типизированный лист). К этому свойству можно биндиться извне и, к тому же, сам контрол использует это свойство для отображения. Но при изменении коллекции как то так `Items.Add("asd")` в отображении ничего не меняется. Это логично, но как сказать отображению, что коллекция изменилась?

Теперь что я пытался с этим поделать.

1. Я пытался сделать `ItemsProperty` типа `ObservableCollection<string>`. Но при использовании контрола я не могу прибиндить ему свойство типа `List<string>` по понятным причинам.
2. Я пытался вызывать `DependencyObject.OnPropertyChanged`, но ничего не получилось.
3. Я пытался в xaml.cs контрола реализовать `INotifyPropertyChanged` и породить событие `PropertyChanged` для свойства `Items`

Так как же поступить?

Comment: Вы хотите, что бы при изменении коллекции, привязанной к вашему свойству `ItemsProperty` элемент на это как-то реагировал, т.е. отображал, что данные изменились?

Comment: @sp7, нет. Для этого я бы просто при использовании контрола привязывал к нему `ObservableCollection<string>`. Это и так будет. Сам контрол при взаимодействии с ним пользователя может менять эту коллекцию. И я хочу контрол реагировал на изменения внутри себя.

Answer (score 3):

Не знаю насколько сильно это вам поможет, но т.к. в большинстве случаев в качестве источника данных выступает `ObservableCollection<T>`, можем этим воспользоваться, поэтому делаем следующее:

1) В пользовательском контроле создаем `DP`.

```
public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty =    
DependencyProperty.Register("ItemsSource", 
             typeof(IEnumerable<object>),           
             typeof(MyUserControl), 
             new PropertyMetadatadefault(IEnumerable<object>)));


public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
{
     get
     {
          return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
     }
     set
     {
         SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
     }
}
```

2) В конструкторе контролла подписываемся на изменение значения вашего `DP`.

```
public MyUserControl()
{
    InitializeComponent();

    var dp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(MyUserControl));     
    dp?.AddValueChanged(this, Handler);
}
```

3) В обработчике на изменение `DP` приводим ваше свойство к `INotifyCollectionChanged`и подписываемся на уведомления об изменении коллекции.

```
private void Handler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
{
     var nc = ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;
     if (nc != null)
         nc.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
}
```

4) Далее реализуем вашу логику, реагирующую на изменения коллекции:

```
private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
{
        // Ваша логика на реакцию об изменении свойства
}
```

---

Все целиком:

```
public partial class MyUserControl : UserControl
{
    public MyUserControl()
    {
        InitializeComponent();

        var dp = DependencyPropertyDescriptor.FromProperty(ItemsSourceProperty, typeof(MyUserControl));     
        dp?.AddValueChanged(this, Handler);
    }

    private void Handler(object sender, EventArgs eventArgs)
    {
        var nc = ItemsSource as INotifyCollectionChanged;

        if (nc != null)
            nc.CollectionChanged += OnCollectionChanged;
    }

    private void OnCollectionChanged(object sender, NotifyCollectionChangedEventArgs e)
    {
        // Ваш код
    }

    public static readonly DependencyProperty ItemsSourceProperty = DependencyProperty.Register(
                                                    "ItemsSource", 
                                                    typeof(IEnumerable<object>), 
                                                    typeof(MyUserControl), 
                                                    new PropertyMetadata(default(IEnumerable<object>)));

    public IEnumerable<object> ItemsSource
    {
        get
        {
            return (IEnumerable<object>)GetValue(ItemsSourceProperty);
        }
        set
        {
            SetValue(ItemsSourceProperty, value);
        }
    }
}
```

Comment: А вы сами это проверили в работе?

Comment: Да, все работает.

Comment: Не совсем то, что нужно, но есть от чего оттолкнуться. Плюсую, но как ответ пока не отмечу

Comment: Опишите тогда более детально вашу проблему.

Comment: Я описал то что мне нужно. Какие нужны подробности? В вашем решении я не могу изменять коллекцию внутри контрола. В данном случае мне останется только понадеяться на то, что в качестве `ItemsSource` прибиндят `ObservableCollection`. Но работоспособность контрола от этого не должна зависеть.

Comment: @sp7: В такой имплементации у вас memory leak: вы нигде не вызываете `RemoveValueChanged`. Плюс вы не отписываетесь от изменений коллекции, ещё один memory leak. Лучше делать так: http://pastebin.com/UZpMTZK5

Comment: @iRumba: Это по идее правильная, типичная имплементация. Если вы хотите, чтобы всегда можно было отслеживать, объявите тип свойства в `UserControl`'е `ObservableCollection<T>` или там `INotifyCollectionChange<T>`. Я бы только поменял `IEnumerable<T>` на `IEnumerable`.

Comment: VladD, здесь я хотел показать общую идею, поэтому многие вещи не реализованы.

Comment: @VladD, я где то выше написал почему не использую в контроле ObservableCollection. К свойству нельзя будет прибиндить лист (и не только)

Comment: @iRumba: Ну это понятно, а почему не использовать так, как в ответе? Что именно не так? Смотрите, в `ItemsControl` какого типа `ItemsSource`?